# Category filter on Sharepoint online events app from different site does not work

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I have an events list on a Sharepoint subsite with multiple values added to the Category column. I have added a bunch of events and each one tagged with several category values

When I try to add an Events app on a page on a different site collection and select the source as my first site, the Category filter does not populate the values to filter our events.

Can someone let me know is by design or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you should enter category values manually in the "Category" to filter events. It's by design.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Even if i enter manually, the webpart is not filtering. In my scenario, I have tried with both "All Sites"  and Select sites options as well.  My category values are like  "ONH - Awareness dates" , "Brand Site - Leading Women webpage"

Comment: Also, we have multiple options/choices enabled for the Category field.